# Unable to connect to smtp (Connection refused)

Tags: php, smtp

I looked around and there are a lot of questions on this issue, but I guess they are all somewhat specific and none seem to have the info I'm looking for.

We recently added the email function to our site so that we can send out automated emails to people who register, forget passwords, etc.  This is set up properly and works fine on the Localhost.

We then pushed the site to a web server and it is not working.  We get the following error message:

> fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection refused)

Followed by a bunch of other errors related to functions that depend on the above connection happening.  We've tried ports 587, 25, and 2525 but no luck.

This is the code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize(array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    'smtp_user' => 'username',
    'smtp_pass' => 'secretpwd',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'mailtype' => 'html'
));

$this->email->from('info@domain.com', 'CompanyName');
$this->email->to($this->input->post('register_email')); 

$this->email->subject('Application Confirmation');

$this->email->message('Hello');

$this->email->send()
```

Answer (score 4):

**You have open relay on your domain!!!!!!!** If you are using postfix please update your main configuration file to this

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination #this is important
    permit 
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

As far as your question goes show me some code. It is hard just from this to make coclusion what is wrong.

Comment: Did you try without 'smtp_user' => 'username','smtp_pass' => 'secretpwd'? First try that and then we will see. This is common problem when trying to send mail from php with auth.

Comment: Thanks again for your response! I guess we just found out that HostGator does not work with SMTP servers.  WTF HostGator.  We are switching to a different service.  Also, I would upvote but I need 15 reputation to do so, I will get my partner to do that.